# Chrome extension for Stack Exchange to extend DOIs into references

Tags: chrome, stack-exchange, reference-management

I am looking for a Chrome extension for Stack Exchange to extend DOIs into references when writing a question/answer/comment.

E.g.:

- Input: https://doi.org/10.1002/ca.21241
- Output: Dundon, J. M., R. J. Markert, and M. W. Lawless. "Correlation between patella and patellar tendon width: an anatomic study." Clinical Anatomy 25, no. 3 (2012): 398-400. https://doi.org/10.1002/ca.21241

Any price and license is fine.

Comment: This is only tangential here, but I will mention that some sites in this network have some kind of citation helper built directly into the editor: [MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/citation-helper/info), [Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22008/lets-get-mathoverflows-citation-helper-here-too).

Comment: @Martin Thanks, good to know! So far their tool seems to only work for mathematical citations (couldn't find this DOI for a nonmathematical publication: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5RmB.png), but that's indeed a great example of how such a Chrome extension or user script could look like.